# How does an empire rise, work and fall

Tags: government, trade

So let’s say that an empire is rising. How does that work? How do the people form an empire? They would need to have some land, a leader, and some natural resources to trade? So now the empire has risen. How does this faze work. For instance, how does a new emperor get appointed? How do they get the money to build cities and what not? How do they get soldiers for war? Lastly, how does the fall of an empire work? Do they run out of resources? Does civil war break out? Are the more then one person fight for leadership? Are they conquered by a rival empire? Now that the empires gone, what happens to the people? The land? The money?
Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=empires&i=stripbooks&rh=n%3A916520%2Cn%3A927728%2Cn%3A928664&dc&qid=1597331212&rnid=927726&ref=sr_nr_n_9) is a link to a few publications on the issue. Once you've read them all you'll probably have 1% of the knowledge you seek, which is still a lot more than we all together can provide on a Q&A site.

Comment: This is probably too broad to be a single question (you've got about 10 questions here). To understand empires you should probably look to historic examples, best place to start is probably edutainment, e.g. crash course on youtube (you'd probably be most interested in the first part of the European history one, though maybe the world history would also give further insights to your questions), maybe also some Economics explained videos. Jumping around using the youtube recommendations and maybe read some related non-textbook books will give you a breadth so you can focus your questions.

Comment: After that you should be able to focus future questions to one aspect of empires, e.g. when an empire is rising what methods are most common for towns to join together into a larger entity? (note this is different to how do nation-states joint together to form an empire). Alternatively you could ask for resource suggestions for a particular aspect or on this topic in general, but specify what kind of knowledge you already have (e.g. where would be the best place to start when trying to understand the rise, peak, and fall of empires for someone who hasn't looked into it before)

Comment: [Though I'm not 100% sure on the community's view on resource suggestion questions]

Comment: This is a great question!  Or rather, this is at least three quite good questions (if, even independently, they are not too broad).  Try narrowing down and asking a single question at a time - like how do empires form, or how do empires fall, or how does succession generally work in an empire.  Be prepared for "it depends on..." or "what time-period/level of technology/cultural assumptions..."

Answer (score 3):

Empires rise because one people or another have some quantifiable advantage in economics, warfare, or culture (this isn't the same thing as claiming their culture is enlightened, however).

Once the empire is formed and well-founded, they work by making trade possible that utilizes comparative advantage. People (even cities!) can specialize, become better than most at some trade good, and then sell it abroad. The large size of the empire allows for the network effect to increase the empire's knowledge base, even to make new discoveries. To invent. The empire is less vulnerable to military defeat. Any enemy is likely too small to pose a real threat, and if somehow they do manage to win an upset victory the empire is robust enough to absorb that loss and win the greater war.

In decline though, there is little mystery either. The empire outgrows its ability to maintain stability. It simply exceeds its capacity to "scale up". It's not a particularly romantic viewpoint (How could the Roman Empire fail? Only some magical factor that is clever could be the true cause!?), but that's the basics. This ability to scale isn't fixed... technology and political sophistication play a part too. If your goon squad can show up in 3 hours to put down a revolt, you can scale larger than if it takes them a 3 week march to do the same. And if you have hundreds of sociologists cranking out research to better let you see the revolt happening before any overt signs... well, you can scale larger still.

Declines are usually slow-motion disasters too. It's not a fall, so much as a "roll down the hill". In some cases, they bleed territory until they're a small rump state. In others they schism/split into multiple squabbling factions. Occasionally, everything manages to blow up simultaneously... but even in those, decades and centuries of strife foreshadows.

Some of the details you ask for aren't really relevant. Does it need an emperor? Not really. The formal title isn't necessary. The USSR had no emperor even if the predecessor did, and yet its territory was greater still. Did someone appoint those guys? Maybe, maybe not. Maybe one seizes power. Or they simply elevate an existing hereditary monarchy further still. Sometimes conscription, sometimes voluntary enlistment. Sometimes mercenaries... occasionally there is prolonged peace eliminating the need for a significant army. The nitpicking stuff is really up to you.